# XML to SQL with SSIS or ADO.NET

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, ado.net

I have to import loads of little XML files to a databse. Now I'm currently doing it with an SSIS script, but it takes a lot of time (aprox 4.000 files in 30 mins).

Would it be faster if I were to make a custom program for this using ADO.NET? Because in total I'd have to transfer aprox. 500.000 files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a batch insert through SSIS?

Comment: @shat90 I made a control flow that has a loop and a data flow task (the one to load the xml to sql). In the data flow task I have the source of the xml files and 3 sql server destinations (since I have 3 tables).

Comment: Try using the Bulk Insert task., it should speeden things up

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141239.aspx

Comment: @shat90 I will give it a go but these xml files have specific tables they need to go to. I can understand that this method works well with text files

Comment: Try using the script task in the data flow instead as a data source.

Comment: Try using the script task in the data flow instead of the control flow as a data source. You can put the loop inside the script to generate output rows (presumably one row per file?). When this flows to your destination it should be much faster as it will to it in batch by default.